# sum of rows formula in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

i have 2 tabs in a google spreadsheet, the first tab contains "country" and "ids"
in the second tab i have a column "country"
i would like to add a formula on the second tab that gives me the sum of all rows (ids) per country
here is the example
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dMvDRjY-oZwQHuZM49B7ksurxjSFc7o1drVHUVbSFFU/edit?usp=sharing
i tried with =IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(ids!B:B,ids!A:A=A2)))
but i get zero
any idea?
thanks!

Comment: think you meant to use `counta` instead of `sum` since you cant sum up text `ID` values.

Comment: You should add column with expected results so it will be clearer what are you aiming for

Comment: thanks @rockinfreakshow this solved it! =IFERROR(COUNTA(FILTER(ids!B:B,ids!A:A=A2)))

Comment: You can also use =countifs(ids!A:A,A2,ids!B:B,"<>")

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
 =SUMIF(countrys!A:A, A2, ids!B:B)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! i tried this =SUMIF(sum!A:A, A2, ids!B:B) on the "sum" tabs but i still get 0

Comment: I somewhat suspect that the possible issue @rockinfreakshow has suggested might be true in your case, could you try and change the value type for ID unless it is actually the count of ID values for each country that you're aiming for?

Comment: thanks guys, i added the expected results on column B here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dMvDRjY-oZwQHuZM49B7ksurxjSFc7o1drVHUVbSFFU/edit#gid=1855132251
basically i would like to have the sum of the number of rows where an id is present (on the "ids" tab), for each country